# why loading into weblogic/domain/lib

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I am working on weblogic 12c and i deploy .ear file which inside contains .jars and project stuff.

After ANT Build all java classes goes as jar inside 'project/bin' folder. This bin folder will be part of  .ear file.

I then deploy .ear on weblogic. But apart from doing this, it is also
forcing me to copy 'project/bin' folder stuff into 'Weblogic/domain/lib' folder and restart the weblogic server.  If i dont do this, i am getting ClassNotFoundException for all java classes.

Why should i copy 'project/bin' folder into 'Weblogic/domain/lib' ?

Is this a ideal way of doing deployment ?
If not, How to avoid doing this every time ?
Please help.

Comment: Probably use an IDE with a weblogic server plugin which handles all the auto deployment while developing for you. take a look at [eclipse + weblogic](https://www.google.de/search?q=eclipe+weblogic&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=lvfLU6WeNs7esgaCxoCwDA#channel=sb&q=eclipse+weblogic&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&spell=1)

Comment: This deployment applies to QA and Production environments. I cannot use IDE in my case.

Comment: Actually your `.ear` archive should contain all its 3rd party dependencies, in `APP-INF/lib` and/or `WEB-INF/lib` for web application specific dependencies. Your own classes go into `APP-INF/classes` or an `ejb .jar` and respectively `WEB-INF/classes`. So you need to fix your ANT script so that it packages/assembles your `.ear` file in this fashion.

Comment: Yes, my .ear is already fashioned in this way. I rechecked. The .ear already contains all stuff. I still wonder why we need to add all the project related to jars to the weblogic/domain/lib folder ?